# loading fancybox in ajax success function

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to load fancybox to display queried info in a div. In Firebug I can see that all went well but the fancybox window does not pop up as I'd expect. What am I missing so that it can pop up?

```
<td><a class="pop" href="#gps_information" id="<?php echo $gps->labref ?>"><?php echo $gps->labref ?></a><input type="hidden" id="labref" value=""/></td> 


<div id="gps_information">    
    </div> 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pop').click(function () {
        labref = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>sample_location/gps/" + labref,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var data = "I am waiting";
                $('#gps_information').html(data);

                $('.pop').fancybox({});

                return true;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations,

1). This

```
$('.pop').fancybox({});
```

...doesn't actually fire fancybox, it only *binds* fancybox to the selector `.pop`

2). if ajax is success, you will end up having two event handlers applied to the same selector

```
$('.pop').click({});
$('.pop').fancybox({});
```

... since the first returns `false`, the second will never take effect.

3). if the idea behind of populating the div (`<div id="gps_information">`) is only to show it in fancybox, then you may not need it at all. You may show the returned ajax `data` directly in fancybox without populating the `div`.

Having said that, you could tweak your code this way :

```
$jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pop').click(function () {
        labref = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>sample_location/gps/" + labref,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //var data = "I am waiting"; // it would override returned data, wouldn't it?
                //$('#gps_information').html(data);
                $.fancybox(data, {
                    // API options here
                });
                // return true; // need no more
            },
            error: function (data) { // (data) what for?
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```